# Building a Unity project with the Affectiva SDK not working post build

Tags: unity-game-engine, face-recognition, affdex-sdk

I've been building a game in Unity using the Affectiva Unity SDK, and I can test the game out within Unity fine - the camera turns on, the SDK is called, and I get the response I was expecting.

Yet when I go to build the project, it claims it builds successfully and the camera is activated when the scene starts.. but I get no responses from the SDK. No errors or anything..

Do I need to package this up specially or something?

Comment: What platform are you building on?  Would it happen to be OS X 32-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you are building a 32-bit app on OS X.  Is that correct?  If it is, can you instead create a universal build or a 64-bit build?  The Unity plugin currently only supports the following build options:

- Windows 64-bit
- Windows 32-bit
- OS X Universal
- OS X 64-bit (x86_64)

For some odd reason Unity defaults OS X builds to 32-bit.  There is documentation about the build requirements on [Affectiva's developer portal at the bottom of the page](http://developer.affectiva.com/v2/unity/#special-notes-on-builds).

Comment: Yep, changing to the 64 bit solved my issue straight away!